# unable to fetch data from DB using Angular JS - Controller

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, database

Please help me in fetching data from database using `Angular JS`.
Error prompting in the console

> [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=u%20in%20o&p1=string%3A%0D&p2=%22%5Cr%22

please check with below screen-shot for your reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post an example of what `pages/details.php` outputs?

Comment: <?php

include("../include/connectionStringFetch.php");


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT main_id FROM dhms_index_table");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $data[] = array(
            'mainID' => $row['main_id']
        );
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>

Comment: also added image of details.php please check. thank you

Comment: Add track by $index to your ng-repeat attribute and see what will you get.

Comment: and very new to it. this my 1st angular project. could you please show example. how can i add $index in ng-repeat attribute

Answer (score 1):

Most likely an issue with duplicates in your ng-repeat. From the Angular [website](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes):

```
 <div ng-repeat="value in [4, 4]"></div>
```

To resolve this error either ensure that the items in the collection have unique identity or use the track by syntax to specify how to track the association between models and DOM.

The example above can be resolved by using track by $index, which will cause the items to be keyed by their position in the array instead of their value:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in [4, 4] track by $index"></div>
```